# SOAP Parsing WSDL error with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I need to connect to a web service with `SOAP`. 
So, I have a key (it gives me by the company owner of the service. It was created to allow the request only from my static IP) because the service requires authentication.

**My code is:**

```
$url = "http://www.visirun.com/public/Server.php?wsdl";
$chiave = Array("key"=>"MYKEY") ;
$funzione = "getFleetCurrentPosition";
$namespace = Array("namespace"=>"urn:Tracking") ;

try {   
$soapClient = new SoapClient($url, $chiave);
$soapResult = $soapClient->__soapCall($funzione, $namespace) ;  
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

This code give me this **error:**

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://www.visirun.com/public/Server.php?wsdl' : failed to load
>   external entity "http://www.visirun.com/public/Server.php?wsdl"

Could someone explain me how to solve this error?